# Html.ActionLink generates the wrong URL, aslways adding Terminal/ to the URL

Tags: asp.net-mvc

When I try to generate an HTML link using

`@Html.ActionLink("Edit Carrier", "EditCarrier", "CustomerCare")`

I would expect it to generate the URL `/CustomerCare/EditCarrier/` but no matter what view I place it in the URL always gets generated as `/Terminal/CustomerCare/EditCarrier/` and am I not sure why `/Terminal/` is being added to the route. This is my first time NOT using Attribute Routing, and it is not an option to use it in this project. From looking around on the web I setup my `RouteConfig.cs` file as:

```
    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Terminals",
            url: "Terminal/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
```

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because the route `Terminals` matches first when you request the url. If you don't use this route, then you can simply remove it from `RouteConfig.cs`, then the url will be `/CustomerCare/EditCarrier/`. If you need the `Terminals` route for any controller, you can add constraints to it:

```
routes.MapRoute(
   name: "Terminals",
   url: "Terminal/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
   defaults: new { id = UrlParameter.Optional },
   constraints: new { controller = @"ControllerWhoNeedsThisRoute" }
);
```

**EDIT:** Alternative you could also use [`@Html.RouteLink()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd493103(v=vs.118).aspx) and add the route name for generating the url. But then you need to specify the controller and the action in parameters. The second parameter is the name of the route to use:

```
@Html.RouteLink("Edit Carrier", "Default", new { controller = "CustomerCare", action = "EditCarrier" })
```

Comment: Is there a modification I can make to the `HTML.ActionLink` to make it not hit the Terminal route? The docs I read said to list the routes from most specific to least and I need this route. The Terminal/ URL will match something like a dozen controllers as well.

Comment: Maybe Terminals should be an MVC Area?

Comment: @MatthewVerstraete I've updated my answer. You could use `@Html.RouteLink()` to specify the route.

Comment: @KevinBrechbühl Using RouteLink worked perfectly. Thanks a lot.